# Customizing site definition files with a Module element

Tags: my-site, my-profile, site-definition

I am customizing a SharePoint 2010 MySite area and part of which deals with customizing the Person.aspx and OrganizationView.aspx pages, which are a part of the MySite site definition.

I am deploying my customized pages via a Module element (via elements.xml). I have set this up within a Solution and it deploys the pages just the way I'd like.

The problem I have is that, once I've deployed the pages this way, I lose the ability to "Reset to site definition" on those pages within SharePoint designer. SPD thinks they're just regular pages now. This is a deal-breaker for me, because I want to be able to retract back to the original state of the MySite at any point in time.

Anybody know how to deploy a customized site definition page and retain the ability to "reset to site definition"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your page is deployed via a feature, it's considered to be *the* site definition, so if you customise it further within SPD, and you reset to definition, it'll reset to as installed by your Feature.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. So with me replacing "Person.aspx", the site is assuming that my new version is the actual Site Definition version. 

So how do I deploy a customized version of a site definition page? Do I have to mess with an onet.xml or a feature staple?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you deployed a customised Person.aspx via a Feature that was loaded with the Site Def, then SP would see that as part of the definition. "Customisations" that can be reverted back to the definition are done via SharePoint Designer or through the user interface.